# pandas : update value if condition in 3 columns are met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
      A      B       C            D
1   blue    red    square        NaN
2  orange  yellow  circle        NaN
3  black   grey    circle        NaN
```

and I want to update column D when it meets 3 conditions. Ex:

```py
df.ix[ np.logical_and(df.A=='blue', df.B=='red', df.C=='square'), ['D'] ] = 'succeed'
```

It works for the first two conditions, but it doesn't work for the third, thus:

```py
df.ix[ np.logical_and(df.A=='blue', df.B=='red', df.C=='triangle'), ['D'] ] = 'succeed'
```

has exactly the same result:

```
      A      B       C            D
1   blue    red    square        succeed
2  orange  yellow  circle        NaN
3  black   grey    circle        NaN
```

Comment: Use the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73687100/19123103) if the other solutions are slow.

Answer (score 80):

Using:

```
df[ (df.A=='blue') & (df.B=='red') & (df.C=='square') ]['D'] = 'succeed'
```

gives the warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

A better way of achieving this seems to be:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] == 'blue') & (df['B'] == 'red') & (df['C'] == 'square'),'D'] = 'M5'
```

Answer (score 28):

You could try this instead:

```
df[ (df.A=='blue') & (df.B=='red') & (df.C=='square') ]['D'] = 'succeed'
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try:

```
df['D'] = np.where((df.A=='blue') & (df.B=='red') & (df.C=='square'), 'succeed')
```

This answer might provide a detailed answer to the your question:
[Update row values where certain condition is met in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36910033/8542145)

Answer (score 4):

This format might have been implied in the new answers, but the following bit actually worked for me.

`df['D'].loc[(df['A'] == 'blue') & (df['B'] == 'red') & (df['C'] == 'square')] = 'succeed'`

Answer (score 3):

The third parameter of [logical_and](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) is to assign the array used to store the result.

Currently, the method @TimRich provided might be the best. In pandas 0.13 (in development), there's a new experimental [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental) method. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

The existing solutions are very slow for large dataframes (100k+ rows); an alternative is to try `numexpr` evaluation with `eval()` method to build a boolean mask and use this mask to replace values using `mask()` method.

```py
df['D'] = df['D'].mask(df.eval("A=='blue' and B=='red' and C=='square'"), 'succeed')
```

As the length of the dataframe increases `eval()` becomes much [faster](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#expression-evaluation-via-eval) than the other alternatives. For example, for a frame with 1mil rows, it is 2.2 times faster than `loc` method outlined in [Praveen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45651450/19123103), [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21263149/19123103) and [Alex Schwab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56575380/19123103)'s answers.

Yet another method is to use `numpy.where()` method to select values according to a condition.

```py
df['D'] = np.where((df.A=='blue') & (df.B=='red') & (df.C=='square'), 'succeed', pd.NA)
```

This is similar to [theSanjeev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47052345/19123103)'s answer; the only difference is to set the "else"-value that is missing in their answer. Speaking of missing values, `pd.NA` is also faster than `np.nan` or `float('nan')` as well.