# Duplicate Rows in Pandas Dataframe if Values are in a List

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
fruit   cost
apples  2
oranges 3
bananas 5
grapefruit  1
```

I want to pass a list that includes specified "fruit" column values and use that to duplicate those rows in the dataframe. For example, duplicated `fruits = ['apples', 'oranges']`.

These rows should then be copied back into the dataframe with an extra column that denotes that they are a copy (can be a binary 1/0).

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Do you want `df['indicator'] = df['fruit'].isin(fruits)`?

Comment: I only want to duplicate "oranges" and "apples," so values I have specified. The desired output is to duplicate these rows in the dataframe and create a new column marking which rows are originals and which are copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for get matching rows and for duplication use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to original data with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for indicato column:

```
duplicated  = ['apples', 'oranges']
df1 = df[df['fruit'].isin(duplicated)].assign(new=1)
df = df.assign(new=0).append(df1, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
        fruit  cost  new
0      apples     2    0
1     oranges     3    0
2     bananas     5    0
3  grapefruit     1    0
4      apples     2    1
5     oranges     3    1
```

Another idea is use parameter `keys` in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) - it create new level filled by `0` and `1`, so necessary [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) by first level for convert this level for column:

```
df = (pd.concat([df, df1], keys=(0,1))
       .rename_axis(('new', None))
       .reset_index(level=0)
       .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   new       fruit  cost
0    0      apples     2
1    0     oranges     3
2    0     bananas     5
3    0  grapefruit     1
4    1      apples     2
5    1     oranges     3
```

Comment: Thanks! Follow up q - if I want to specify that row now, i.e. where apples is duplicated (fruit = apples, new = 1) and I want to replace "apples" with "apple juice," how could I do that replacement?

Comment: @dataelephant use `m =(df['fruit'] =='apples') & (df['new'] ==1)` and then `df.loc[m, 'fruit'] = "apple juice"`

Comment: @dataelephant also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36910033/2901002).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
result = pd.concat([df, df[df.fruit.isin(fruits)].assign(new=1)], sort=False).fillna(0)
```

**Output**

```
        fruit  cost  new
0      apples     2  0.0
1     oranges     3  0.0
2     bananas     5  0.0
3  grapefruit     1  0.0
0      apples     2  1.0
1     oranges     3  1.0
```

As an alternative you could reindex, with default_value=0, before concat:

```
filtered = df[df.fruit.isin(fruits)].assign(new=1)

result = pd.concat([df.reindex(columns=filtered.columns, fill_value=0), filtered], sort=False)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
        fruit  cost  new
0      apples     2    0
1     oranges     3    0
2     bananas     5    0
3  grapefruit     1    0
0      apples     2    1
1     oranges     3    1
```