# Updating a DataFrame cell at a row other than the index using the `.at` method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I'm working on some real world geometric data using GeoPandas, which relies on Pandas.

I don't really care about the index in my [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) (it has been assigned automatically) but when it comes to updating a single cell based on a condition in one or more specific columns (instead of the index), in the following example, a building `Identifier` column, I wish I can benefit from the [`.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) operator as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842088/set-value-for-particular-cell-in-pandas-dataframe-using-index) or [there](https://re-thought.com/how-to-change-or-update-a-cell-value-in-python-pandas-dataframe/).

For the moment, I'm extracting the index value where my condition is met to be able to use [`.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) method:

```
# gdf is a GeoDataFrame
gdf.at[gdf[gdf['Identifier'] == mybuilding.identifier].index.values[0], 'geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries([shape]).iloc[0]
```

The `gdf[gdf['Identifier'] == mybuilding.identifier].index.values[0]` part is only used to extract the index properly for the [`.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) method to work.

Otherwise, if I'm using the [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method, the column I want to update is not updated (and I don't know why, because [it should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36910033/6630397)...):

```
gdf.loc[gdf['Identifier'] == mybuilding.identifier, 'geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries([shape])
```

and the following raises the error `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`:

```
gdf.loc[gdf['Identifier'] == mybuilding.identifier, 'geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries([shape]).iloc[0]
```

(`shape` is a [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) MultiPolygon instance)

Is there a more pythonic (but still efficient) way to go?
Because if the first solution is actually working, it's rather cumbersome to write...

An SQL equivalent would be:

```
UPDATE geodataframe SET "geometry" = <shape> WHERE "Indentifier" = mybuilding_indentifier;
```

Version info:
GeoPandas: '0.12.1'
Pandas: '1.5.1'
Shapely: '1.8.5.post1'
Python: 3.10.6

*If I have missed a duplicate, I will delete my question if I am pointed to an existing working solution with clear explanations.*

Comment: Hi, what does `gpd.GeoSeries([shape])` look like?

Comment: It's a `geopandas.geoseries.GeoSeries` instance containing a single Polygon: `0    POLYGON (((706331.272 320147.755 456....
dtype: geometry` In some other cases it's a single `MULTIPOLYGON`. Nothing fancy here.