# Python Pandas: Execute comparison between columns in two DataFrames if values in their rows are equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `df1` and `df2`. Each dataframe contains an ID column. Each dataframe also contains a geometry column. I would like to calculate the distance between each dataframe's geometry column only for rows where ID's match in each dataframe.

I would imagine it looks something like this but can't figure it out:

```
for geom in df1.geometry:
    if df1['system_id'] == df2f['systemID']:    
        df1['distance'] = [geom.distance(df2.geometry[0].boundary) for geom in df1.geometry]
```

Comment: Something like this? `distance = df1[df1['system_id'] == df2['systemID']].geometry.distance(df2.geometry[0].boundary)` Distance here might not have the same number of rows as df1.

Answer (score 0):

There's the function .equals()

```
df1['system_id'].equals(df2f['systemID'])
```

which will return a boolean

Comment: Not sure how I'd implement that into the rest of my code as I also need to compare values in each df's geometry column

Comment: In that case, I guess this should be helpful then [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909977/update-row-values-where-certain-condition-is-met-in-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909977/update-row-values-where-certain-condition-is-met-in-pandas)