# Creating a new variable with lots of conditions, combining blank and categorical values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks generally like this

```
ID Loc SL_Local SL_State TP Overall
12 54X          E        I  D
45 86I D        I        H  E
98 65R H        H        H  H
```

I want to create a new column (SL), that uses the SL_Local and SL_State columns with some if/then logic.  Basically if SL_Local is blank then SL = SL_State, else if SL_Local = D and SL_State = I then SL = D, and so on.  In total, there would be around 20 possible combinations.

I've found some examples of using if/else logic to create flags (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702342/creating-a-new-column-based-on-if-elif-else-condition)), but that's not quite what I'm looking for.  I've also found some questions about having multiple conditions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263020/pandas-update-value-if-condition-in-3-columns-are-met/21263149)), but that returns `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1131952,) (2,)` and doesn't seem to work with the blank values.  I tried this logic on a column with NaNs considering blanks might be too challenging to work with, but that wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Use np.select

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[12,45,98],'Loc':['54X','86I','65R'],'SL_Local':['','D','H'],'SL_State':['E','I','H'],'TP':['I','H','H'],'Overall':['D','E','H']})
df = df[['ID','Loc','SL_Local','SL_State','TP','Overall']]
df
```

Out:

```
    ID  Loc  SL_Local   SL_State    TP  Overall
0   12  54X                E        I      D
1   45  86I    D           I        H      E
2   98  65R    H           H        H      H
```

then do

```
condition_list = [
          (df['SL_Local'] =='') & (df['SL_State'] is not None),
          (df['SL_Local'] == 'D') & (df['SL_State'] == 'I')
           ]
choice_list = [df['SL_State'], 'D']

df['SL'] = np.select(condition_list, choice_list, default = '')
df
```

Out:

```
   ID  Loc    SL_Local    SL_State    TP    Overall    SL
0  12  54X                   E         I       D        E
1  45  86I        D          I         H       E        D
2  98  65R        H          H         H       H
```